# socket.io can't send custom json object that contain farsi/arabic words

Tags: json, node.js, socket.io

when i want to emit a json object that contain farsi words in socket.io but
socket.io loop and loop again and never send emit event to client.
but if i remove farsi words from my json object it's work correctly and send emit.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('info', function(){
const finalMsg = JSON.stringify({"action":"message",
                "msg":{"id":11,"city_id":6,"car_plate_city_code":0,
                    "first_name":"رحیم ","last_name":"رضایی",
                    "car_name":"پژوه"}});

socket.emit('driver', finalMsg);

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I know it's late but if someone used base 64 and it didn't fix the issue 
Here's what solved it for me 
- upgrade your socket gradle to latest version  in my case it's

```
//SOCKET IO LIBRARY FOR RUN TIME CHATTING AND RUNTIME FLASHING
compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to invalid JSON format ,server is throwing an error.Missing Comma before first_name.Try with below json.

```
const finalMsg = JSON.stringify({"action":"message",
                "msg":{"id":11,"city_id":6,"car_plate_city_code":0,
                 "first_name":"رحیم ","last_name":"رضایی",
                "car_name":"پژوه"}});
```

Comment: i converted my farsi/arabic words to base64 encode and now problem solved.

Comment: or maybe because my client is android not a web browser. thanks anyway.